# Minimal primary decomposition

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, ideals

> Let $m$ be an integer ${\geq}3$ and $f(x,y,z)=y^m(x+y^3)-z^3$ in $k[x,y,z]$. Find the singular points of $f$ and find a minimal primary decomposition of the jacobian of $f$.

I find the set of singular points of $f$ to be {$(x,0,0): {x\in k} $} and the jacobian to be $\langle y^m,mxy^{m-1},-3z^2\rangle$. How do I find a minimal primary decomposition?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume the characteristic of $k$ is such that $3\ne 0$ and $m\ne 0$.

Then $$\langle y^m,mxy^{m-1},-3z^2\rangle=\langle y^m,z^2,xy^{m-1}\rangle=\langle y^m,z^2,x\rangle\cap \langle y^{m-1},z^2\rangle $$ is a minimal primary decomposition.

Comment: and these two are primary beause their radicals, respectively $<y,z,x> and <y,z>$ are maximal. Is that correct?

Comment: The second is not maximal in $k[x,y,z]$, but it is in $k[y,z]$ and extending a primary ideal from $k[y,z]$ to $k[x,y,z]$ this remains primary.